# TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to use javascript highcharts but getting this error:-

TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function
    data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]

The highcharts libary file is been included but still it's not working.
my code is:

```
<head>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<script>
function analytics()
{
            $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        });

}   

</script>
<head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="ok" id= "button" onclick="analytics()">
</body>
```

Comment: Where is your jQuery script tag? (You haven't shown it in the code above.) Is it above or below the highcharts one? If it's below, that's the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are including your jquery script file  below your highchart library, include it above it and try it might be the solution.